# Failed to create an IDataAdapter object. This provider may not be fully supported with the Execute SQL Task

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I executed a simple query inside an execute SQL task -

```
SELECT col1, col2
from thetable
where code = ?
order by id asc
```

Exec sql task - ADO.NET connection
parameter "code" is an int32 in SSIS and int32 in parameter mapping of exec sql task.

It works fine in SQL server, but in SSIS it causes the error -

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "SELECT col1, col2
from thet..." failed with the following error: "Failed to create an IDataAdapter object. This provider may not be fully supported with the Execute SQL Task. Error message 'Incorrect syntax near '?'.'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

How do I fix this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADO.NET uses a different syntax (@) for parameters - [Map Query Parameters to Variables in an Execute SQL Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355.aspx)

You are using `?` as the parameter marker, which works for OleDb and ADO, but not for ADO.NET.  Try replacing `?` with `@code` and, then in your Parameter mapping, change the Parameter Name to @code:

```
SELECT col1, col2
from thetable
where code = @code
order by id asc
```

[image]

Comment: yes, I tried it like this for multiple parameters - @ p1, @ p2, @ p3, @ p4 etc...No space between the @ and name. ADO.NET connection seemed a little slower than OLEDB though.

Comment: and sometimes this thing just happens due to random reasons. I solved it by copying the task from an older version of the file. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message and it ended up being that IsQueryStoredProcedure property was set to True.  I was calling a stored procedure, but this would not be appropriate when using syntax like "Exec MySP..."